# Leaflet Marker cluster error

Tags: javascript, angularjs, leaflet, angular-leaflet-directive, leaflet.markercluster

I'm implementing leaflet map with clustering markers using angularjs. When button click, the leaflet map has to been shown as empty layer. I got some web console-error. I already install the below packages using bower

```
bower install angular-leaflet-directive --save
bower install leaflet-plugins --save
```

It automatically added plugins in index.html

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="bower_components/leaflet/dist/leaflet.css" />
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="bower_components/leaflet.markercluster/dist/MarkerCluster.css" />
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="bower_components/leaflet.markercluster/dist/MarkerCluster.Default.css" />
    <script src="bower_components/leaflet/dist/leaflet-src.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/leaflet/dist/leaflet.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/angular-leaflet-directive/dist/angular-leaflet-directive.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/leaflet.markercluster/dist/leaflet.markercluster.js"></script>
```

But i couldn't able to resolve these web-console error. Please tell me how do i resolve this issue;

[image]

Comment: Is `bower_components/leaflet/dist/leaflet-src.js` being loaded? Check the network tab in the browser's dev tools.

Comment: Or simply look at all console messages, instead of just errors

Comment: So I've noticed Leaflet is very vague when it comes to undefined errors. You should include your code so we can look. I've had the ```L is not defined``` for things as trivial as using ```addTo(map)``` instead of using ```addLayer(map)```.